# How to get the position of tab android?

Tags: android

I am Having the small doubt on tab-widget.

- How i can get the position of tab widget dynamically?
- Assume that there are of 20 tabs,when i clicked on the 10 tab i need to display the position of that tab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use OnTabChangeListener interface to TabHost

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.OnTabChangeListener.html
`onTabChanged(String tabId)`
this will give you String id of selected tab
and use `setCurrentTabByTag(String tag)` of TabHost to get current Tab

**or**

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html
`String  getCurrentTabTag()` will give currentTab Tag string
`int     getCurrentTab()` will give you currentTab int position

Comment: then one more small help..by selecing on that tab it need to come in to center.

Comment: place this in another question, as this question is about completely different thing

Answer (score 3):

```
MainTabHost tabparent;
tabparent = (MainTabHost) getParent();
tabparent.getTabHost().getCurrentTab()
```

Assuming that you want to access it from a child activity of the tab.

Comment: What is `MainTabHost` here?

Comment: whichever class that extends the Tabhost, this is deprecated now I think...use tabactivity and fragments

Answer (score 2):

In your TabActivity implement    OnTabChangeListener

then set the listener for the TabHost `mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);`

```
@Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        Log.i("selected tab index", "Current index - "+mTabHost.getCurrentTab());

    }
```