# How to set the position of a Tab programmatically?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I am developing an sample application with tab-host,and i have achieved it.
And here is my problem? i will describe it in steps.

- assume that there are 5 tabs with position 0,1,2,3,4.When i selected the fourth tab it should be replaced on second tab.

How can i overcome from this issue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7873522/how-to-get-the-position-of-tab-android/7873643#7873643

Answer (score 1):

It is strait forward if I understood you correctly

```
tabHost.setCurrentTab(index)
```

*> EDITS*

You can make your tab's invisible

as 
if you want to invisible tab at position 0 then it is as follow.

```
      tabWidget = (TabWidget) findViewById(android.R.id.tabs);
      tabWidget.getChildTabViewAt(0).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

If you want make it visible it is as follow

```
 tabWidget.getChildTabViewAt(0).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

but if you want to remove old tab and replace it with new. Then I don't know it is possible or not

Comment: ok i will agree with u,but my requirement, i am having three tabs named as 1,2,3, i want to replace each other.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
FrameLayout frame = tabHost.getTabContentView();

View view1 = frame.getChildAt(pos1);
View view2 = frame.getChildAt(pos2);

frame.removeViewAt(pos1);
frame.addView(view2, pos1);

frame.removeViewAt(pos2);
frame.addView(view1, pos2);
```

This should switch tab in `pos1` position with tab in `pos2` position
I have not checked it, but it should work :)

Comment: When I can check it, I help you. In this moment it's impossible for me. Anyway, this is an idea about how you can resolve it. See ViewGroup documentation... I hope that helps you